# What is Blend parameter in Unity Animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

When I do some changes to my animators, sometimes I notice a float parameter named `Blend` with value of `0.0` appears in the parameter list of the animator.

[image]

I think this happens when I change blending mode or weight of a layer.

[image]

I didn't find any documentation for this. Anyone knows what does this parameter do and how to use it, Is it safe to delete it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you see this parameter, maybe with a small screen snippet? What do you mean by 'change blending option of a layer'? As your question currently stands I don't know if you're talking about Blend Trees, Blend Shapes, Animation.Blend, or something else entirely.

Comment: Ok. I added some screenshots

Comment: Well, that goes above my knowledge of unity animation, but the question is much clearer. I'm sure you're right about the blend parameter being tied to the additive layer blending, but I don't know how it works or where specific documentation for it can be found. Hopefully somebody more knowledgable will give an answer soon. In the meantime I'd probably look through blend trees and blend shapes documentation to see if you can find any answers there.

Comment: Hey I'm taking a look at the animator now and I'm not getting a random Blend parameter. Are you sure it's not a plugin or something that's doing it? Can you try the same thing with a blank Unity project? If it still happens can you add exact reproduction steps?

Comment: @Nonameghost I'm not sure how it happens, I will try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend is a default float variable they included for you to use in your scripts. You can safely remove it if you wish. The method for controlling animator variables is [Anim.SetFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html). For example you might want to replace it with 'movementDirection' on a character controller. In [Mechanim](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animate-anything-mecanim) you control blends between x and y axis of animation combinations using external variables such as Blend

Comment: could you be more specific? `control blends between x and y axis` like morphing two animations?

Comment: Exactly. It's all in the docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html